# Horizontally center a list of items with only the width of their content

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical list of items:

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something else</li>
  <li>Nothing</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6roe6y30/5/

I'd like to horizontally center the list items within the `ul`, but I'd like their widths to be based off whatever the content inside is. Eg: the 'Hi' li should be the smallest and the 'Something else' li should be the widest.

In their default state, the list items fill the width of the ul. I've tried variations of `display` but to no affect.

Due to the limitations of the CMS I'm using, I cannot alter the HTML.

Would anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something else</li>
  <li>Nothing</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap your text in `<span>`s and set your background color CSS on the `<span>`.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Something</span></li>
    <li><span>Something else</span></li>
    <li><span>Hi</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
 list-style: none;
}

span {
  background: red;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: auto;
}
```

See it in action here:  https://jsfiddle.net/kylemartin/8vyapLL9/

Comment: Really sorry! I forget to mention in the question that I can't alter the HTML its self. This is a good solution otherwise, though.

Comment: I see that Michael_B has gotten a working example before I was able to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by treating list elements as if they're in a table:

> li { display: table-cell; }

but this will stick them together.

If you need them to be separated I would recommend using **flex**